# Compiler error exposing Swift function with PHAssetCollectionSubtype enum type argument to Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have a small function that takes an argument of type `PHAssetCollectionSubtype`

```
func loadSmartAlbum(subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype) -> PHFetchResult {
    return PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(
            PHAssetCollectionType.SmartAlbum, subtype: subtype, options: nil)
}
```

The compiler gives an error in the auto-generated Swift header:

```
DerivedSources/MyApp-Swift.h:204:46: Expected a type

- (PHFetchResult * nonnull)loadSmartAlbum:(PHAssetCollectionSubtype)subtype;
                                           ^
```

I can't see what is wrong with the above. `PHAssetCollectionSubtype` is a well defined integer enum in both Swift and Obj-C.

When I click on the definition in the header file, XCode navigates to the Obj-C definition of the enum.

Looks like a bug in the compiler?

Comment: in XCode 7.0.1 it works fine for me

Comment: I'm using XCode 7.0.1 too.